# How to Call Method in Fragment From Parent Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**Here is the Fragment I want call getAvailableWebsites(); from parent Activity **

```
public class Earn extends Fragment {


public Earn() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_earn, container, false);
}
public void getAvailableWebsites(){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Called From Activity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below option in your Activity:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof YourFragment) {
    ((YourFragment) fragment).yourFragmentMethod();
}
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

- Implement an interface b/w your fragment and activity.
  [Read this for more clarity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

Comment: It useful too, Thanks